# Django: passing queryset to the intermediate page of admin action?

Tags: django

## Goal

My goal is to write a "Export selected as CSV" action in Django admin site.

After reading [link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages) I think it's a good idea to redirect my export request to a customized view.

Here's the question: how can I pass the current `queryset` to the intermediate page?

The method in [link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages) doesn't work if you choose all instances (refer [link2](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/12282/admin-selectacross.diff)).

## My current solution

In order to get the queryset in the intermediate page, I have two choices:

1. `pickle` the `queryset.query` and send it to the intermediate page with `?qs={picked_qs_query}`, then recreate the `queryset` in the intermediate page. This in my opinion is a good solution, and makes the intermediate page idempotent.
2. save the queryset in session and load it in the intermediate page. It's simple but makes the page not idempotent enough.

And, of course I can just ignore the intermediate page and return CSV content in the "Export selected as CSV" action, but is it really a good idea?

## Any better idea?

Thank you for reading this question :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use Django's default `delete_selected` action as a template. It uses an intermediary page and does so without complicated pickling and such.

See: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/actions.py

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After re-consider my question, I realized that I don't need to _redirect_ to the intermediate page. Instead, I should just return the intermediate page in the action.

Comment: This sourcecode omits the very important `selected = request.POST.getlist(admin.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME)`. Make sure you also read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Is problem to generate QuerySet later in view? If not, do it that way;

view part:

- write custom view
- generate QuerySet in view
- add QuerySet into template context
- render it

admin part:

- just create action and pass required parameters to generate QuerySet in view

Comment: But my question is, how to do "generate QuerySet in view". Your answer didn't answer my question :-(